# Does reinvesting dividends after selling for a loss cause a wash sale?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, dividends, wash-sale, dividend-reinvestment

I sold some fund shares with high turnover on my personal investment account with the intent of buying something similar later on my IRA account.  However, after I sold (and within 30 days), I received dividends on the leftover shares which I have set to automatically invest into shares.  Have I created a wash sale?  I've seen questions asking with something similar, but I'm not sure if order matters between dividend and selling.

Presuming I have caused a wash sale: if I sold 100 shares, then got a 2 share "dividend" via reinvestment of my other shares, can I still use the 98 shares as a loss or is the entire transaction considered a wash sale?

Comment: Was all of this in the same tax year? If so then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think my question was pretty specific that I was asking which shares are considered a wash share.  Yes, a dividend reinvestment causes a wash sale per the referenced question, but it did not specify which portion was considered a wash (only the dividend amount, not the entire original sale).


Also, the referenced question is a buy-dividend-sell situation within the allotted time.  My situation was more a sell-dividend; although now I understand the dividend is essentially a buy on my behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you realize loss and you  purchase new shares in the same security within 30 days (before or after),  a wash sale occurs.  This also applies to reinvested dividends.  The portion of the loss allocable to the reinvestment will be disallowed and must be carried forward.